# How to read float notation in golang?

Tags: go

When printing out some values from a map of structs. I see certain float64 values with alternative notation. The test passes but how do you read this notation (4e-06).  Is this value indeed the same as "0.000004"?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func TestXxx(t *testing.T) {

    num := fmt.Sprintf("%f", float64(1.225788)-float64(1.225784)) // 0.000004  
    f, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(num, 64)
    if f == 0.000004 {
        t.Log("Success")
    } else {
        t.Error("Not Equal", num)
    }

    if getFloat(f) == 0.000004 {
        t.Log("Success")
    }else{
        t.Error("Fail", getFloat(f))
    }
}

func getFloat(f float64) float64 {
    fmt.Println("My Float:",f) //  4e-06
    return f
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The notation is called [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), and it is a convenient way to print very small or very large numbers in compact, short form.

It has the form of

> *m* × 10<sup>*n*</sup>

(*m* times ten raised to the power of *n*)

In programming languages it is written / printed as:

> *m*`e`*n*

See [Spec: Floating-point literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals).

Your number: `4e-06`, where `m=4` and `n=-6`, which means `4*10`<sup>`-6`</sup> which equals to `0.000004`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to print your floats in a regular way you can do something like this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)


func main() {
    a, _ := strconv.ParseFloat("0.000004", 64)
    b, _ := strconv.ParseFloat("0.0000000004", 64)
    c := fmt.Sprintf("10.0004")
    cc, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(c, 64)
    fmt.Printf("%.6f\n", a)     // 6 numbers after the point
    fmt.Printf("%.10f\n", b)    // 10 numbers afer the point
    fmt.Printf("%.4f\n", cc)    // 4 numbers after the point
}
```

Output:

```
0.000004
0.0000000004
10.0004
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the same number. You can use `fmt.Printf("My Float: %.6f\n",f)` if you don't like the scientific notation. (This format requests that 6 digits will be printed after the decimal point.)